# what is the history of naming newborn in different community?

Tags: names

Did every tribe or community in history named their newborn babies from time immemorial? Was it a cultural tradition to every community on earth?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.babble.com/baby-name-articles/baby-naming-traditions/amp/

Comment: I'm not sure this is history - sociology or anthropology perhaps, but I don't think it is amenable to historical sources and methods.  40K years of human history across the entire globe is too broad to answer.  The question would also benefit from documenting preliminary research.

Comment: In my extended family, newborns aren’t named until a few weeks after birth, possibly because in previous generations it wasn’t always clear if they would live that long. Is that what you’re asking about?

Comment: I agree with your comment @Mark C. Wallace. I too had a feeling that it is not the right site to ask this question...

Answer (score 1):

It might be. For reference, [sperm whales](http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2011/03/14/134534139/researcher-sperm-whales-might-give-each-other-names) and [dolphins](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2013/07/130722-dolphins-whistle-names-identity-animals-science/) seem to be giving each other names too. I'm not finding any indication through cursory googling that chimps or bonobos are doing so as well, but I wouldn't be too surprised if they did so too.